# Apply function to all columns but restricted to the rows within each level of a class in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a df with many numeric columns, and one factor variable (catvar) with three levels (A, B and C). I have a function which performs some esoteric calculations and returns a new dataframe with a new column titled "estimatefinal". This works fine, however I would like this to be applied separately for each of the levels of "catvar". How can I do this?

This is my function, though the specifics of it aren't necessarily relevant:

```
bestpercentile <- function(x){
n = 10
auc_final <- array(0, dim = c(n, n, n))
for (i in 1:n){
for (j in 1:n){
  for (k in 1:n){
    findbest <- function(x){
      x <- spare
      x$income_per <-apply(x[,6:9], 1, quantile, probs = i/n, na.rm = T)
      x$purchases_per <-apply(x[,10:13], 1, quantile, probs = j/n, na.rm = T)
      x$expenses_per <-apply(x[,14:18], 1, quantile, probs = k/n, na.rm = T)
      x$estimate <<- x$income_per-x$purchases_per-x$expenses_per
    }
    findbest(x)
    model <- glm(default ~ estimate, data = x, family = "binomial")
    auc_coef <- performance(prediction(predict(model , x, type="response"), x$default), measure = "auc")
    auc_final[i,j,k] <- auc_coef@y.values[[1]]
  }
 }
}
  optimumpercentile <- which(auc_final == max(auc_final), arr.ind = TRUE)
x$income_per <-apply(x[,6:9], 1, quantile, probs = optimumpercentile[1]/10, na.rm = T)
x$purchases_per <-apply(x[,10:13], 1, quantile, probs = optimumpercentile[2]/10, na.rm = T)
x$expenses_per <-apply(x[,14:18], 1, quantile, probs = optimumpercentile[3]/10, na.rm = T)
x$estimatefinal <- x$income_per-x$purchases_per-x$expenses_per
return(x)
}
```

The end result would be exactly what I would get if I was to split the df into three for each of the levels of "catvar" then run the function three times for each of those new df's and then finally to rbind the three three together. of course I count do it that hacky way, but I would rather have a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: This can be accomplished using group_by() in dplyr.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153654/how-to-use-group-by-and-do-in-dplyr-to-apply-a-function-for-each-factor-leve